# Sharepoint Search results are'nt items but List

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010

With Sharepoint 2010 Server, I am Searching "toto" with a Basic Search Center WebPart.

Instead of retrieving items, I get lists.

Instead of get Url like http://server/Lists/myList/DispForm.aspx?ID=299777
I get an Url like       http://server/Lists/myList/AllItems.aspx

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm New In Sharepoint. Trouble came with a crawling error. 
Next time I'll see Craw Log before asking a Question.

the error was an Unexpected Token Error in the Site Data Web Service during Crawl.
trouble source is a white space in the Field Name of a column based on a termset

see : [... is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manuj/archive/2010/06/03/unexpected-token-error-in-the-site-data-web-service-during-crawl.aspx)